# Application windows content get displayed (upside down !) while session is locked

Tags: kde, nvidia, display, steam

I recently experienced a very bizarre phenomenon. As I thawed my computer from suspend, I got back to my session manager's lock screen. However, the content of the window of application currently running in the session was displayed intermittently, and with a 180°-rotation.

As a picture is better than a thousand words, here is a photography (not a screen capture) of my screen displaying the content of Thunderbird's window (the tessellation was added afterwards for obvious privacy reasons) :
[image: a computer screen displaying KDE's lock screen, and Thunderbird !]
Notice the bottom part of the screen, where the taskbar would go, is unaffected, and correctly displays (not upside down) the background of the lock screen. Also note that Thunderbird was not the only application to be displayed. The whole thing flickers, sometimes displaying a given window for less than one second.

The system is otherwise responsive. However, unlocking the session did not end that behaviour. In fact, I had already experienced it some month ago without session locking being involved : that was then an annoyance, but its happening while the session is locked is a more important privacy problem.

Closing then reopening the session (without restarting the whole computer) put an end to the phenomenon.

I am at a loss because it is difficult for me to **describe the phenomenon concisely in English**, and therefore to search for that topic ; I also do not know **where to report that bug**, considering the many elements involved.

Namely :

- OS is KUbuntu 22.04 (up to date), with kernel 5.15.0-82-generic, KDE Plasma 5.24.7, KDE Frameworks 5.92.0, Qt 5.15.3, Xorg-server 21.1.4,
- GPU is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650/PCIe/SSE2,
- GPU driver is nvidia 525.125.06.

Also, Steam window was running at the time (it sometimes has display artefacts so this may be relevant).

Comment: What is your question exactly? For now your post is just a story.

Comment: They are in bold, but phrased indirectly : how would you describe this more concisely, and where should this be reported as a bug, in your opinion. Of course, if somebody has more insight into this, that would be very interesting as well.

Comment: That looks like a screensaver, using a desktop screen capture to create a paved stone-like pattern.  What screensaver is your desktop using, and how is it currently configured?  EDIT: Oh, you modified that manually. Ok. So it's unrelated to the screensaver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tentatively classify that as a **failure to restore GPU state on resume from suspend**. More specifically, it appears that the *display composition information* did not get properly restored.

It is possible that an **intermittent hardware failure** (e.g. an unreliable spot in GPU memory) might be involved too. The flickering and the fact that you said Steam sometimes has display artifacts also hints at that possibility.

Since you are using NVidia's proprietary driver, **this should be reported to NVidia only.** If you want to know more, you might post to [NVidia's Linux driver development forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148): you might get a more detailed answer there.

As far as I've understood, a modern GPU has usually plenty of video RAM to hold most or all windows (even ones that are currently hidden) as separate bitmaps, with a separate *display composition information* telling it how the windows should be placed on screen (potentially overlapping each other) and which of them should and shouldn't be displayed at any given moment. Since the window bitmaps are not so different from textures, the GPU hardware options to mirror/resize/rotate/otherwise warp textures can be equally applicable to them.

It seems to me that your situation was most likely caused by the display composition information getting corrupted, resulting in the GPU hardware semi-randomly rendering various window bitmaps that should have been off-screen at the time, with an incorrect mirroring/rotation applied to them.

Closing and reopening the session causes the X display server to reset, which should cause a fairly major reinitialization of the GPU state, so that might explain why the problem went away.